# Problema ao abrir um modal

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces, bootsfaces

Estou usando um framework chamado `BootsFaces` e toda vez que tento abrir um modal a partir de um `commandButton` o modal abre porém fica desse jeito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o modal não fica habilitado.

botão que abre o modal:

```
<p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <b:commandButton icon="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"
                value="Pesquisar" look="success" style="margin-left:1px"
                ajax="true" oncomplete="$('.modalPseudoClass').modal();"
                update="frmPrin" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

modal:

```
        <b:modal id="amodal" title="Cadastrar Contrato"
            styleClass="modalPseudoClass" closable="false"
            close-on-escape="false" backdrop="false">

            <p:outputLabel value="Código" />
            <b:inputText fieldSize="sm" readonly="true"/>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <b:button value="Voltar" dismiss="modal" onclick="return false;" />
                <b:commandButton value="Salvar" look="primary" dismiss="modal"
                    oncomplete="return false;"
                    update=":msgGlobal :frmPrin" />
            </f:facet>
        </b:modal>
```

Comment: já tentou abrir ele pelo <b:button>?

Comment: Já sim, fica da mesma forma

Comment: [pt] Tanto quanto eu posso ver, a sua página XHTML é correto. Eu tenho duas idéias: Talvez o problema é PrimeFaces. Você usa algo como p: blockUI? A imagem parece um blockUI ativa. Em segundo lugar, tentar o meu projeto de demonstração em https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples/tree/master/ModalDialogs. Qual a versão do BootsFaces você usa?

Comment: [en] As far as I can see, your XHTML page is correct. I've got two ideas: Maybe the problem is PrimeFaces. Do you use something like p:blockUI? The screenshot looks like an active blockUI. Second, try my demo project at https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples/tree/master/ModalDialogs. Which version of BootsFaces do you use?